# Carregar skrollr.init da maneira correta em Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parallax

Estou utilizando o **Skrollr** em uma aplicação **Rails** da seguinte forma:

#### Gem Utilizada:

```
gem 'skrollr-rails'
```

#### app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require skrollr
//= require skrollr.menu
$(document).on("ready page:load", function () {
    var s = skrollr.init({
        smoothScrolling: false,
        mobileDeceleration: 0.004
    });

    skrollr.menu.init(s, {
        animate: true,
        scale: 2
    });
});
```

Tenho uma página principal onde tenho um layout *parallax* e mais algumas outras páginas com detalhamento de alguns produtos e serviços.

### O problema:

O init é feito no "*ready page:load*", entretanto ao navegar entre as páginas ele pára de funcionar funcionando novamente somente se eu der um *refresh* na página.
O que pode ser feito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta sendo carregado corretamente, para funcionar basta adicionar o código conforme abaixo:

```
// => skrollr.init()
s.refresh();
```

Desta forma o **Skrollr** estará recarregando os elementos da página.

**[Documentação oficial](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#refreshelements)**